# Save & Load generic Data WinPhone8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

First of all, I'm developing a **WindowsPhone8.1** app which has a JSON (name, telephone number, email-...) file from the web. I store this JSON data in a list (contact is a class which has the parameters from the JSON.

I want to store (local no Cloud) this list on my WindowsPhone (its a List with marked favorites, not the whole list).

I tried it with StorageFolder and StorageFile, unfortunately, I failed. Got a problem with deleting and loading the files.

Developing in Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 3 with C#, Xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this class, you need Json package which is available via nuget.

```
 class StorageService : IConfigurationService
        {
            readonly StorageFolder _local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            public async void Save<T>(string key, T obj)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);


                var dataFolder = await _local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder",
            CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(key,
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, json);
            }

            public async Task<T> Load<T>(string key)
            {
                try
                {
                    var dataFolder = await _local.GetFolderAsync("DataFolder");
                    var file = await dataFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(key);

                    string json;
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(file))
                    {
                        json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return default(T);
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question
I want to save List<contact> not a JSON.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can't save an object as it is. You should first serialize it to json/xml/whatever and then save it to file as a string.

Comment: Do u also know a method for deleting all Files in the Folder?